# Android application crash diagnostics

Tags: android, crash

I have an Android app for API >=23. It installs on user's device manually via USB (I can't publish it on Google Play).

What is the best way to log crashes of my app on user's device? I would like to have similar data as when I debug my app in Android Studio where I can see all the different system messages, exceptions and even my messages that I output using Log.i(...) in my app in Logcat windows of Android Studio.

Is it e.g. possible to save the logcat output that is produced by released app to a file? Is it guaranteed that the file will contain all messages that came before my app crashed (it is important for me to see the exception that caused the crash)?

Or is there any better practice hwo to log and analyze crashes on a released Android app?

Comment: If you will write all the logs in a file, it will degrade app's performance, there are a lot of online sdks available to keep track of crashes, Firebase crashlytics is quite popular among them, ypu will get every single detail, user device info, last screen opened and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Firebase Crashlytics for debugging specific errors, or dashboarding errors.

It's so simple to use on your app.

For more information, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics?hl=ko